# Prevent TFS of detecting packages contents in different folders

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I've used [.tfignore and Nuget.config](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2015/07/09/ignore-all-nuget-packages-in-tfs/) solution to prevent tfs of detecting changes in packages folder, at the moment it is not detecting the packages folder changes anymore but whenever I add a new package or update the existing one it will detect the changes in possibly *Scripts* or *Content* folders. The problem is I cannot explicitly ignore the Scripts and Content folders because there are some custom scripts that have to be checked-in, what I would prefer is just somehow to ignore the scripts caused by package change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the specify files or include specify files in Scripts and Content folders. For example:

```
#Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
ProjA\xxx.cpp

# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!xxx.dll
```